# Can I publish over FTPS (Ftp over SSL)

Tags: 2011, publishing

Can i configure Tridion 2011 SP1 to publishing over FTPS protocol (FTP over SSL)?

Comment: This is not possible ootb as Raj  pointed out. I'm curious, why would you like to FTPS instead of HTTPS?

Answer (score 12):

You have default option for SFTP not FTPS in Tridion. but Tridion allows custom implementation also.

you can also check following sdllivecontent url http://goo.gl/BGZb2 ([*Requires login*](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/documentation/sdltridion.aspx))
Its says:
A default installation of SDL Tridion does not support the following protocols:

- SCP (Secure Copy), which uses SSH1 (Secure Shell version 1)
- FTPS,also known as FTP/SSL, that is, FTP using SSL (Secure Socket Layer).

Comment: Are you sure about bullet 1? As far as I remember what most people call SCP is what Tridion offers as SSHFTP.

Answer (score 12):

Verify first that there is a valid reason for use a protocol that is not offered Out of the Box

In case you are interested in using a protocol that is not available in the product, here are some steps so you can get started:

1. Create a new protocol schema and add the required fields (The name of the schema has to match with the Type attribute you use in the Sender node (Mentioned in the Documentation))
2. Develop your own sender (You can have a look at one of the existing senders as for instance "FTPTransportConnector"). Probably you'll have to use some external libraries that implement the required actions for deal with the protocol
3. Add the jar file in the [TRIDION_HOME]\lib folder or register the class in the system CLASSPATH  (Mentioned in the Documentation)
4. Configure the new Sender and Protocol in the cd_transport_conf.xml

   > ```
   > <Senders>
   >   <!-- Install custom Senders by providing a 'Type' that matches the root
   >        element name of a Management System Protocol Schema. The 'Class'
   >        attribute specifies the Java class that implements the functionality
   >        for a Sender. Make sure the class is registered on the system
   >        CLASSPATH environment variable. -->
   >   <Sender Type="Local" Class="com.tridion.transport.connection.connectors.FileTransportConnector"/>
   >   <Sender Type="HTTP" Class="com.tridion.transport.connection.connectors.HTTPSTransportConnector"/>
   >   <Sender Type="HTTPS" Class="com.tridion.transport.connection.connectors.HTTPSTransportConnector">
   >       <!--
   >       <Pooling MaxDestinationConnections="20" MaxTotalConnections="200"/> 
   >        -->
   >   </Sender>
   >   <Sender Type="FTP" Class="com.tridion.transport.connection.connectors.FTPTransportConnector"/>
   >   <Sender Type="SFTP" Class="com.tridion.transport.connection.connectors.SFTPTransportConnector"/>
   >   <Sender Type="SSHFTP" Class="com.tridion.transport.connection.connectors.SSHFTPTransportConnector"/>
   > </Senders>
   > ```